# in jdbc createStatement() is which class method

Tags: java, jdbc

please explain createstatement is the abstract method in the connetion interface,so this method is defined in which class

```
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
 Statement st=con.createStatement();
```

Comment: the underlying Connection Implementation, thus it depends on the specific JDBC driver you're using.

Answer (score 5):

It's *declared* in [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) which is an interface.

It's *implemented* in some concrete class based on the actual connection returned by `DriverManager.getConnection`, which will depend on the connection URL you provide.

If you're new enough to Java that abstract methods are causing you confusion (and we were all newbies once) I would *strongly* suggest you back away from JDBC. Play around with small console apps which just look at language features, after reading the tutorials on [abstract classes and methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). Then when you're confident, go back to JDBC.